# How to compile DB and DD assembly instructions using GCC compiler

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

I am trying to compile a legacy module(written in C) in my project using gcc compiler. I am using codeblocks IDE for compilation. I was able to resolve most of the issues i faced but not able to compile the below inline assembly code using gcc.

```
extern void *RegisterTable;

    void REGISTER(void) {
      asm db 0,0,0
      asm dd word ptr RegisterTable
    }
```

gcc not able to identify db and dd instructions. Hence I tried to change the above code as shown below in the hope of compiling in gcc

```
    extern void *RegisterTable;
    void REGISTER(void) {
      asm
      (
      ".byte 0,0,0\n\t"
      ".long word ptr RegisterTable\n\t"
      );
}
```

But this code also giving below error in the second line "".long word ptr RegisterTable\n\t"" as it is not able to recognize the PTR

> Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `p'

Any help on how to compile this assembly code using gcc is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The assembler used is 'as' which comes by default with gcc. Also this piece of code is to put the address of 'RegisterTable' function in a particular location - to be specific the first 'db' instruction puts the three zeros as the first 3 bytes of the code segment and the second 'dd' instruction puts the address of the RegisterTable function as the 4th bit of the code section - of the binary file.The binary file is in PE format(windows file format). And the downstream process which process the binary file looks for this address for its processing. It is done by reading the PE header structure first and then finding the code section from the PE header and after finding the start of code section the downstream process uses the below code to read the address of the RegisterTable function which was put by the above code in my question

```
  // Get Registration table 
  fseek(f, Section.ptrToRaw+3, SEEK_SET); //Skip the 0,0,0
  fread(&ptrTab, sizeof(ptrTab), 1, f);
  M->RTab = GetRegisterTable32(M->Mem, ptrTab-PEHdr.imgBase-PEHdr.baseOfData);
```

Comment: Inline assembly is assembled by the assembler (which the `gcc` command invokes, depending on circumstances), not the compiler proper. As such, it is dependent on the assembler and the target system, and there are variations in assembler syntax and directives. You would need to specify details of your target system. Additionally, code using inline assembly like this is typically dong something system-specific and nonportable, and you should not expect to get it working merely by reproducing the assembly. You may need to understand what it was doing and design a modern replacement.

Comment: That said, it does not appear the routine is doing anything useful. Those two assembly directives generate some data and do not contribute any executable instructions to the function. Additionally, they do not declare a label to refer to the data. So they seem useless. You will need to understand what the original code was using them for.

Comment: Thanks @EricPostpischil for the reply, I have updated my question with the assembler name and the high level view on what this code is doing.

Comment: You can try changing `".long word ptr RegisterTable\n\t"` to `".long word ptr RegisterTable\n\t"`. However, this code is still not portable. When GCC generates code for functions, it includes standard prologue instructions for its target. Any software that attempts to find this data stuffed into a function will not be able to do so unless it knows exactly what prologue GCC generates, so it can skip it. The data in the old software would have been located differently. Whatever this is, it is a poor design. It is easy to include a label in assembly code and use that for locating data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I am afraid, i think you have mentioned the same assembly instructions for me to try in your comment which I have asked in my question

Comment: Oops, I meant to change `".long word ptr RegisterTable\n\t"` to `".long RegisterTable\n\t"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc allows you to use inline asm outside of functions.  So you can simply do the following, *outside* of any function:

```
asm(".text \n\t"
    ".byte 0,0,0 \n\t"
    ".long RegisterTable");
```

This will place, within your code section, three zero bytes followed by the address of `RegisterTable`.

Note that the GNU assembler does not need anything analogous to `word ptr`; that is specific to MASM-like assemblers that want to keep track of object types.

If your platform uses leading underscores on C-defined symbols, then you may have to use `_RegisterTable` instead.

If the symbol `REGISTER` is used anywhere (not in the code you showed), then:

```
asm(".global REGISTER \n\t"
    ".text \n\t"
    "REGISTER: \n\t"
    ".byte 0,0,0 \n\t"
    ".long RegisterTable");
```

The hard part, however, is going to be to ensure that those three bytes are *first* in your executable's code segment.  Just putting it at the top of your `.c` file probably won't work reliably.  There is a good chance that the compiler and/or linker will place something else ahead of it, such as startup or library code.  You may be able to accomplish this with a linker script but it may be painful.  This is something I think you should ask as a separate question.

In the long run, your best bet may be to figure out why the program needs to be parsing data out of its own executable files, as that's a weird thing to do, and redesign that aspect to use something that's easier and less fragile (e.g. read it from a separate flat file, or load a DLL).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer, it helps a lot. Now with the changes suggested by you, GCC is not complaining about the assembler code.